# Hazelcast predicate for empty list field

Tags: caching, hazelcast, predicate

I have an object like following :

```
class Motorbike {
    List<Wheel> wheels;
}

class Wheel {
   String name;
   List<Long> brands;

}
```

I am trying to implement a Hazelcast predicate to retrieve all Motorbike objects in the map that have name = "ABC" and empty brands.

Is this something that can be achieved using Hazelcast predicates ?

Any ideas : hints would be very appreciated.

Thanks.

I came through this :

```
Predicate p = Predicates.equal("wheels[0].name", "ABC");
```

but it seems to apply to an array wheels not to a list.

How to implement an empty list predicate remains unknown to me.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me

```
class TestData implements Serializable {

  private List<TestData1> list = new ArrayList<>();

  public List<TestData1> getList() {
    return list;
  }
  public void setList(List<TestData1> list) {
    this.list = list;
  }
}
class TestData1 implements Serializable {
  private String attr1;

  public TestData1(String attr1) {
    this.attr1 = attr1;
  }
  public String getAttr1() {
    return attr1;
  }
  public void setAttr1(String attr1) {
    this.attr1 = attr1;
  }
}
IMap<String, TestData> map = instance1.getMap(...);
TestData testData = new TestData();
List<TestData1> list = testData.getList();
list.add(new TestData1("1"));
list.add(new TestData1("2"));

map.put("a", testData);
map.executeOnEntries(new MyEntryProcessor(), 
  Predicates.equal("list[0].attr1", "1"));
```